# How can I transfer the attributes of parent elements to child elements in XML using python?

Tags: python, xml, xml.etree

Given the following structure of XML file:

```
<root>
    <parent attr1="foo" attr2="bar">
        <child> something </child>
    </parent>
    .
    .
    .
```

how can transfer the attributes from parent to child and delete the parent element to get the following structure:

```
<root>
    <child attr1="foo" attr2="bar">
    something
    </child>
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to find `<parent>`, then find `<child>`, copy attributes from `<parent>` to `<child>`, append `<child>` to root node and remove `<parent>`. Everything is that simple:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
    <parent attr1="foo" attr2="bar">
        <child> something </child>
    </parent>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
parent = root.find("parent")
child = parent.find("child")
child.attrib = parent.attrib
root.append(child)
root.remove(parent)
# next code is just to print patched XML
ET.indent(root)
ET.dump(root)
```

Result:

```xml
<root>
  <child attr1="foo" attr2="bar"> something </child>
</root>
```

Comment: Apparently `ET` doesn't have a `indent ` attribute. `AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'indent'` Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Asdoost, starting from python 3.9 ;)